# Issue on setting up newRelic on Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I installed newrelic on my OS(Ubuntu 14.04) in python3.4, then generate newrelic.ini via license key, after that I run this command:

```
sudo newrelic-admin run-program python backend/__main__.py
```

but after that i've get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/newrelic-admin", line 9, in <module>
 load_entry_point('newrelic==2.50.0.39', 'console_scripts', 'newrelic-admin')()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/newrelic-2.50.0.39/newrelic/admin/__init__.py", line 128, in main
 callback(sys.argv[2:])
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/newrelic-2.50.0.39/newrelic/admin/run_program.py", line 96, in run_program
 os.execl(program_exe_path, *args)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/os.py", line 489, in execl
 execv(file, args)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

i've run that with sudo but it throws permission denied anyway! why this happens and how can i prevent this? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like, based on the stack trace, you want to change the permissions on the `run_program.py` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the permission of your bootstarp file in your project like this:

```
sudo chmod 755 YOUR_FILE.py
```